# Selecting a row to change the view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have created the view controllers and attached those to control their respective views.  I can't figure out how to make the following code to go the right views, though (this is in the root view controller):

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     RunViewController *runViewController = [[RunViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RunView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     CalcViewController *calcViewController = [[CalcViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalcView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     PushViewController *pushViewController = [[PushViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     SitViewController *sitViewController = [[SitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SitView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
     TimerViewController *timerViewController = [[TimerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimerView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:runViewController animated:YES];
     [runViewController release];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:pushViewController animated:YES];
     [pushViewController release];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:sitViewController animated:YES];
     [sitViewController release];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:timerViewController animated:YES];
     [timerViewController release];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:calcViewController animated:YES];
     [calcViewController release];

     runViewController = nil;
     pushViewController = nil;
     sitViewController = nil;
     timerViewController = nil;
     calcViewController = nil;
}
```

Each time I select any of the rows in the table - all of the views come up.  How do I arrange them to only open the view that it is supposed to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `pushViewController:animated` on every view controller. If you only want one of the view controllers to come up just call `pushViewController:animated` only on the one you want. Here's a sample:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

    // This code shows a different view depending on the selected row.
    UIViewController *viewController = nil;
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            viewController = [[RunViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RunView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;

        case 1:
            viewController = [[CalcViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CalcView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;

        case 2:
            viewController = [[PushViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PushView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;

        case 3:
            viewController = [[SitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SitView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;

        case 4:
            viewController = [[TimerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TimerView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            break;
    }

    if (viewController != nil) {
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
        [viewController release];
    }
```

}